# values are not submitted to database table using php mysql and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using php, MySQL, and Ajax. When I submit the form data is not stored in the database table. But when put action="insert.php" data is submitted to the database table but the page gets refreshed. I am badly stuck here. Can anyone please advice me that how can I solve this problem?? Thanks in advance guys. codes are given below :

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post">
            <label>Roll No : </label>
            <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll"><br>
            <label>Name : </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            <label>Stream : </label>
            <select name="stream" id="stream">
                <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
                <option value="IT">IT</option>
                <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
                <option value="ME">ME</option>
            </select><br>
            <label>Age : </label>
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cForm').on('submit', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"insert.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$('#cForm').serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data == 'ok')
                    {
                        document.getElementById("cForm").reset();
                    }   
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
    <?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $roll=$_POST['roll'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $stream=$_POST['stream'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO `student`(`name`, `stream`, `age`) VALUES ('$name','$stream','$age')";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(isset($result))
     {
      echo 'ok';
     }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: echo your query in insert.php and check the ajax call response

Comment: @akshaykhairmode doesn't solve anything

Answer (score 1):

If you want your page doest not refresh. you need to remove form submission form jQuery because you have called on submit and it called the whole form and send it to next page and do it like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post">
            <label>Roll No : </label>
            <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll"><br>
            <label>Name : </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            <label>Stream : </label>
            <select name="stream" id="stream">
                <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
                <option value="IT">IT</option>
                <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
                <option value="ME">ME</option>
            </select><br>
            <label>Age : </label>
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
            <input type="button" class="btn-submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btn-submit').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"insert.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:$('#cForm').serialize(),
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if(data.status == 200)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("cForm").reset();
                        }   
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And your insert.php page replace

```
echo "ok";
```

by

```
echo json_encode(['status'=>200,'message'=>'success']);
```